# Deselect edges programmatically in Shiny in visNetwork

Tags: r, shiny, visnetwork

I want to deselect edges in a visNetwork network in Shiny. `visSetSelection` should work, but it doesn't: if I select an edge manually, then press the button, the edge remains selected. I don't know of any other way to do it. This https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/1670 suggests using visSelectEdges and setting the id to NULL but this also has no effect. Any ideas?

```
require(shiny)
require(visNetwork)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$network <- renderVisNetwork({
    # minimal example
    nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3)
    edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3))

    visNetwork(nodes, edges)
  })

  observeEvent("deselect",{
  visNetworkProxy("network") %>%
    visSetSelection(edgesId = NULL,unselectAll = T) 


})
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  visNetworkOutput("network"),
  actionButton("deselect","Deselect")
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `visUnselectAll` (see [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/visNetwork/man/visUnselectAll.html)). Also, you need to replace `"deselect"` by `input$deselect` in the condition of `observeEvent`.

```
require(shiny)
require(visNetwork)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$network <- renderVisNetwork({
    # minimal example
    nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3)
    edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3))

    visNetwork(nodes, edges)
  })

  observeEvent(input$deselect, {
    visNetworkProxy("network") %>%
      visUnselectAll()

  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  visNetworkOutput("network"),
  actionButton("deselect","Deselect")
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```